# Qt/QML How to return QList<T> collection from virtual data metod from QAbstractListModel

Tags: qt, qml, qabstractitemmodel, qabstractlistmodel

I want to summarize What to do. I have an `DataObject` class which have members:

```
QString first;QString last;QList<SubObject*> m_sublist;
```

I am using `QAbstractListModel` to this. I can refer first and last to listview but I can't refer to like `m_sublist[0].lesson`. It gives me error like:

> Cannot read property 'lesson' of undefined.

My code:
**dataobject.h**

```
        class SubObject :public QObject
    {
        Q_OBJECT


    public:
        SubObject(const QString &lesson,QObject *parent = 0);
        const QString lesson;

    private:


    //    bool operator==(const SubObject*  &other) const {
    //           return other->lesson == lesson;
    //    }

    };

    class DataObject :public QObject{

        Q_OBJECT
    public:
    DataObject(const QString &firstName,
                const QString &lastName,
                const QList<SubObject*>   &sublist);


    QString first;
    QString last;
    QList<SubObject*> m_sublist;
    };
```

**simplelistmodel.h**

```
    class SimpleListModel : public QAbstractListModel {
        Q_OBJECT
    public:
        SimpleListModel(QObject *parent=0);
        QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role = Qt::DisplayRole) const;
        int rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) const;
        QHash<int,QByteArray> roleNames() const { return  m_roleNames; }



    private:
    // Q_DISABLE_COPY(SimpleListModel);

        QList<DataObject*> m_items;
        static const int FirstNameRole;
        static const int LastNameRole;
        static const int SubListRole;
    QHash<int, QByteArray> m_roleNames;
    };
```

**simplelistmodel.cpp**

```
        const int SimpleListModel::FirstNameRole = Qt::UserRole + 1;
    const int SimpleListModel::LastNameRole = Qt::UserRole + 2;
    const int SimpleListModel::SubListRole = Qt::UserRole + 3;


    SimpleListModel::SimpleListModel(QObject *parent) :
            QAbstractListModel(parent) {
        // Create dummy data for the list

        QList<SubObject*> mysublist;
        mysublist.append(new SubObject("MAT"));
        mysublist.append(new SubObject("FEN"));


        DataObject *first = new DataObject(QString("Arthur"), QString("Dent"),mysublist);
        DataObject *second = new DataObject(QString("Ford"), QString("Prefect"),mysublist);
        DataObject *third = new DataObject(QString("Zaphod"), QString("Beeblebrox"),mysublist);
        m_items.append(first);
        m_items.append(second);
        m_items.append(third);



    // m_roleNames = SimpleListModel::roleNames();
    m_roleNames.insert(FirstNameRole, QByteArray("firstName"));
    m_roleNames.insert(LastNameRole, QByteArray("lastName"));
    m_roleNames.insert(SubListRole, QByteArray("subList"));


    }

    int SimpleListModel::rowCount(const QModelIndex &) const {
    return m_items.size();
    }

    QVariant SimpleListModel::data(const QModelIndex &index,
                                                int role) const {
        if (!index.isValid())
            return QVariant(); // Return Null variant if index is invalid
        if (index.row() > (m_items.size()-1) )
            return QVariant();

        DataObject *dobj = m_items.at(index.row());
        switch (role) {
        case Qt::DisplayRole: // The default display role now displays the first name as well
        case FirstNameRole:
            return QVariant::fromValue(dobj->first);
        case LastNameRole:
            return QVariant::fromValue(dobj->last);
        case SubListRole:
            return QVariant::fromValue(dobj->m_sublist);

        default:
            return QVariant();
        }
    }
```

**main.cpp**

```
        int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

        QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

        QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
        SimpleListModel model;


        QQmlContext *classContext = engine.rootContext();
        classContext->setContextProperty("absmodel",&model);

        engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/myuiscript.qml")));

        return app.exec(); }
```

**myuiscript.qml**

```
        import QtQuick 2.0
    import QtQuick.Window 2.0
    Window {
        id: bgRect
        width: 200
        height: 200
            color: "black"
            visible: true

            ListView {
                id: myListView
                anchors.fill: parent
                delegate: myDelegate
                model: absmodel

            }
            Component {
    id: myDelegate
            Item {
    width: 200
            height: 40
            Rectangle {
                anchors.fill: parent
                    anchors.margins: 2
                    radius: 5
                    color: "lightsteelblue"
                    Row {
                        anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
                            Text {

    text: firstName
            color: "black"
            font.bold: true
                            }
                        Text {
    text: subList[0].lesson
            color: "black"
                        }
                    }
            }
            }
            }


    }
```

I can't find any solution. Virtual data model returns single type of objects. `FirsName` is a string. I cant refer listview delegate like `firstName(rolename)`. Also `LastName` is refered like `lastName(rolename)`. But I can't refer `subList(roleNames)` like `sublist[0].lesson`.

My target is very simple. I want to refer single type `(int,QString ....)` to text in delegate by using rolename. I can't refer collection `type(QList<SubObject*>)` to text in delegate using `rolename(subList[0].lesson)`. How to achive them?

Comment: If `m_sublist` is a `QList<SubObject*>`, then why are you trying to access it like `m_sublist[0].lesson` and not `m_sublist[0]->lesson`?

Comment: @SergeyTachenov , IN QML side , can you write code like -> notations

Comment: Is `DataObject` registered type in QML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's fix it step by step. This line `text: subList[0].lesson` in QML produce the error message

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'lesson' of undefined

That means `subList[0]` is an undefined object and QML engine cannot read any property, including `lesson`, from this object. In fact, `subList` returned from model is a well-defined `QList<SubObject*>` object, but not `subList[0]` since `QList<SubObject*>` is not a QML list. To correctly [pass a list from C++ to QML](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-data.html#qvariantlist-and-qvariantmap-to-javascript-array-and-object), return a `QVariantList` instead of `QList`.

```
//class DataObject
DataObject(const QString &firstName,
            const QString &lastName,
            const QVariantList &sublist);
QVariantList    m_sublist; //use QVariantList instead of QList<SubObject*>

//---
//SimpleListModel::SimpleListModel
QVariantList mysublist; //use QVariantList instead of QList<SubObject*>
mysublist.append(QVariant::fromValue(new SubObject("MAT", this))); //remember parent
mysublist.append(QVariant::fromValue(new SubObject("FEN", this)));
//...
```

Now, `subList[0]` can be accessed in QML, but not `subList[0].lesson`. To [access properties in a C++ class](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-exposecppattributes.html#exposing-properties), explicitly define the property with `Q_PROPERTY` macro.

```
class SubObject :public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QString lesson READ getLesson NOTIFY lessonChanged)

public:
    SubObject(const QString &lesson,QObject *parent = 0):
        QObject(parent), m_lesson(lesson){;}
    QString getLesson() const {return m_lesson;}

signals:
    void lessonChanged();

private:
    QString m_lesson;
};
```

And the QML code works now.

Comment: a `QList<SubOject*>` isn't a list in QML but a `QList<QObject*>` is.